# Are services in AEM really singleton?

Tags: osgi, aem, aem-6

I have an interface which I have implemented. I have annoted the impl with @Component and @Service of the package org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.

I wrote a simple constructor for my impl

```
public MyImpl(){
LOG.info("New instance created!!");
}
```

I also added loggers in @activate and @deactivate method.

I expected to see "New instance created!!" only once BUT I can see activate and deactivate method being called per request I make on a page(This service is invoked by A Sling Model which is used in that page)

What I saw was "New instance created!!" logged several times.

This means the OSGi container create multiple instances of my Service and called the activate and deactivate method every time.

This shows that this is not a Singleton.

The Object should be discarded only when I uninstall my bundle.

Please help me understand what is going on here.

**I WANT TO IMPLEMENT A TRUE SINGLETON IN AEM**

I have implemented this in AEM 6.5 instance which uses Apache Felix.

Edit:

Adding Service properties:

```
aemRootUrl  http://localhost:8080
api.http.connections_manager.timeout    60000
api.http.cookie_max.age 18000
api.http.max_connections    200
api.http.max_connections_per_host   20
api.http.timeout.connection 300000
api.http.timeout.socket 300000
api.server.ssl.trust_all_certs  true
api.server.url  https://10asdasdsad
api.server.username admin
component.id    3925
component.name  com.example.foundation.core.connection.impl.HybrisConnectionImpl
non_akamai.api.server.url   hadasdadasd
service.bundleid    585
Service PID com.example.foundation.core.connection.impl.HybrisConnectionImpl
service.scope   bundle
Using Bundles   com.example.dumb-foundation.core (585)
```

Values altered to hide client specific information

**EDIT::**
I've removed the SCR annotations and replaced them with OSGI annotations here I've explictly specified

```
@Component(service =HybrisConnection.class, immediate=true,scope = ServiceScope.SINGLETON)
```

But still is shows as scope=bundle.

Should I enforce Singleton and OSGi annotations on it's dependencies as well for this to be a proper Singleton?

Comment: Can you share your service's properties from /system/console/components or /system/console/services?

Comment: @mahsum Added them as you mentioned

Comment: Btw. You should switch to the official declarative services annotations. The felix ones are deprecated.

Comment: can you add the part on how the reference is obtained in sling model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In declarative services (which is what you use behind the scenes) there are some cases when a component (and its service) is unpublished.

By default a simple component with immediate=true will come up when the bundle starts and go down when it stops.

If your component has any mandatory service dependencies (@Reference) then it will only be active while all dependencies are present. So if at least one dependent service goes away the component will be deactivated.

In addition the component might get restarted when config is not present at start but added later. If you want to avoid this make the config required.

Comment: I've replaced SCR annotations with OSGi that didn't help. Can you suggest something else

Comment: Replacing the annotations is just to keep up to date. It should not change the behaviour. Can you post all references of the component?

Answer (score 0):

Every thing @Christian Schneider said is true. 
They AEM services are Singletons but are deactivated/unpublished at times. This might be for various reasons.

I faced a horrible issue because of ConfigurationAdmin service. Using this services caused our OSGi config files to be bound to the wrong bundle i.e. SlingModels. bundle within AEM.

the only way to access this is by getting the service using configAdmin.getConfig(PID).setBundleLocation(null);

BUT Doing this causes the service that is linked to this configuration to restart.

So every time I did config.setBundleLocation(null) the service restarted.

**The best and most awesome way to resolve this is use OCD to define configuration for OSGi Services linked to OSGi config.xmls**

**AND NEVER EVER EVER use configuration Admin**

If you want to access properties of another service Say ServiceA want to read ServiceB's title property set in com.example.serivce.impl.ServiceB.xml

Then in ServiceB in the @activate method read the props from OCD config and set it in instance level and have ServiceA inject ServiceB as it's dependency and use the property needed.

eg.

```
 class ServiceA{
@Reference
private ServiceB serviceB;

  public void someMethod(){
   serviceB.getTitle(); // Successfully read property of another service i.e. 
   ServiceB without using ConfigurationAdmin.
  }
}
```